# Expected to decode Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swift5

**Response**

```
    [
  {
    "result": "success",
    "category": [
      {
        "categoryID": "1",
        "category_name": "Health",
        "category_image": "1573456796.jpg",
        "about": "Start your health journey with scientifically developed, guided meditations across below listed verticals",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": "fitness|energy|strength",
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided health meditations to build stronger emotional, mental & physical health",
        "added_on": "2019-11-22 03:21:36",
        "no_items": "7"
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "2",
        "category_name": "Work",
        "category_image": "1556794807.jpg",
        "about": "Accelerate your work life with scientifically developed, guided meditations across below listed verticals ",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": null,
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided work meditations to release stress, foster progressive mindset & excel at work.",
        "added_on": "2019-05-02 04:30:07",
        "no_items": "2"
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "3",
        "category_name": "Relationships",
        "category_image": "1556794814.jpg",
        "about": "Illuminate your relations with scientifically developed, guided meditations across below listed verticals",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": null,
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided relationship meditations to create a deep & loving bond with the self and others",
        "added_on": "2019-05-02 04:30:14",
        "no_items": "0"
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "4",
        "category_name": "Mindfulness",
        "category_image": "1556794819.jpg",
        "about": "Rewire your brain & turn your NOW into WOW™ with scientifically developed, guided mindfulness meditations",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": null,
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided mindfulness meditations to develop focus & awareness in order to turn your NOW into WOW™",
        "added_on": "2019-05-02 04:30:19",
        "no_items": "0"
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "5",
        "category_name": "Students",
        "category_image": "1556794824.jpg",
        "about": "Spark up your student life with scientifically developed, guided meditations across below listed verticals ",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": null,
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided student meditations to strengthen mind power in order to emerge as a super student",
        "added_on": "2019-05-02 04:30:24",
        "no_items": "0"
      },
      {
        "categoryID": "6",
        "category_name": "Affirmations",
        "category_image": "1556794832.jpg",
        "about": "Prime your mind, body & emotions with scientifically developed, affirmations across below listed verticals.",
        "color": "",
        "special": "N",
        "tags": "tags|testing|search",
        "is_active": "Y",
        "description": "Explore guided affirmations to train your mind & body to unleash the infinite potential within",
        "added_on": "2019-05-02 04:30:32",
        "no_items": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Error**

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

**Implementation**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct Library : Codable {
    let result : String?
    let category : [Category]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case result = "result"
        case category = "category"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        result = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .result)
        category = try values.decodeIfPresent([Category].self, forKey: .category)
    }

}
struct Category : Codable {
    let categoryID : String?
    let category_name : String?
    let category_image : String?
    let about : String?
    let color : String?
    let special : String?
    let tags : String?
    let is_active : String?
    let description : String?
    let added_on : String?
    let no_items : String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case categoryID = "categoryID"
        case category_name = "category_name"
        case category_image = "category_image"
        case about = "about"
        case color = "color"
        case special = "special"
        case tags = "tags"
        case is_active = "is_active"
        case description = "description"
        case added_on = "added_on"
        case no_items = "no_items"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        categoryID = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .categoryID)
        category_name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .category_name)
        category_image = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .category_image)
        about = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .about)
        color = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .color)
        special = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .special)
        tags = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tags)
        is_active = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .is_active)
        description = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .description)
        added_on = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .added_on)
        no_items = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .no_items)
    }

}
extension Library {

    init(data: Data) throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        self = try decoder.decode(Library.self, from: data)
    }

    init(_ json: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws {
        guard let data = json.data(using: encoding) else {
            throw NSError(domain: "JSONDecoding", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
        }
        try self.init(data: data)
    }

    init(fromURL url: URL) throws {
        try self.init(data: try Data(contentsOf: url))
    }

    func jsonData() throws -> Data {
        return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    }

    func jsonString(encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) throws -> String? {
        return String(data: try self.jsonData(), encoding: encoding)
    }
}

// MARK: - Alamofire response handlers
extension DataRequest {
    fileprivate func decodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>() -> DataResponseSerializer<T> {
        return DataResponseSerializer { _, response, data, error in

            print(response)

            guard error == nil else { return .failure(error!) }

            guard let data = data else {
                return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))
            }

            return Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) }
        }
    }

    @discardableResult
    fileprivate func responseDecodable<T: Decodable>(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: decodableResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func responsePhoto(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Library>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return responseDecodable(queue: queue, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pratik Sodha Please help

Comment: Add your API calling request code.

Comment: Your outermost object in your JSON is an array, not a dictionary - exactly as the error tells you - You need to decode `[Library].self` not `Library.self`

Comment: @Paulw11         self = try decoder.decode([Library].self, from: data) they show error Cannot assign value of type '[Library]' to type 'Libray

Comment: @Paulw11 please help

Comment: @VarunSinghal why do you use `self =` ? Try this code `let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Library].self, from: data)` and after this `print(result)`

Comment: Your `Library` extension makes no sense because you cannot decode the JSON array.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev return Result { try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data) }Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to closure result type 'T'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot assign the decode to self because it different type I mean self means Library but what we are decoding is array of Library so .

```
init(data: Data) throws {
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       self = try decoder.decode(Library.self, from: data)
   }
```

Example I have taken response to string for easy parsing

```
var stringText = """
[
{
"result": "success",
"category": [
{
"categoryID": "1",
"category_name": "Health",
"category_image": "1573456796.jpg",
"about": "Start your health journey with scientifically developed, guided meditations across below listed verticals",
"color": "",
"special": "N",
"tags": "fitness|energy|strength",
"is_active": "Y",
"description": "Explore guided health meditations to build stronger emotional, mental & physical health",
"added_on": "2019-11-22 03:21:36",
"no_items": "7"
}
]
}
]
"""
```

```
let jsonData = Data(responceString.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let responceData = try decoder.decode([Library].self, from: jsonData)
    print(responceData)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I think this is a much better approach but in the `catch` don't use `localizedDescription` since that gives a more general error description. Use `print(error)` instead for a better and more detailed error message

Answer (score 0):

write

```
return Result { try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data) }
```

instead of

```
return Result { try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) }
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to closure result type 'T' . they give error